# Can't edit EDMX Models

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio

I recently changed my dev computer, after that I reinstalled VS2013, everything compiles fine, but when I try to edit my EDMX model, it says something like this

```
There is no editor available for   "D:\....\MyModel.edmx"
```

I reinstalled EF tools but the problem persists.

What I'm missing ?